# Dropout in Tensorflow CNN network while using triplet based training

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have implemented distance learning using triplets of data using a CNN in Tensorflow. For this I have a shared set of weights for each layer. I want to employ dropout  technique to compensate for over-fitting. I was thinking of doing this in the following way:

```
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
h_fc2_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc2, keep_prob)
h_fc3_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc3, keep_prob)
```

Here, *h_fci* are the outputs for the three data samples from a previous layer. This poses a potential problem in the sense that dropout is probabilistic hence even if I am providing the same dropout probability, it is possible that different set of neurons are dropped for each of the three outputs whereas ideally I would want the same set of neurons to be used for each. What would be the proper way to implement dropout in this context then ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything has the same shape, setting the same seed should make them all identical.

In practice though data samples are minibatched, and `tf.nn.dropout` will drop out the same units in the entire minibatch, so switching to stacking your examples is probably a good idea here.